# Accessing files on Android phone from Python on a Desktop

Tags: python, android, windows

When I connect my android phone to a (Windows) desktop via a USB cable, I would like to automate downloading photos and other files from the phone to the desktop by using a script, preferably Python, but C# would do.

Is there a ready package available for this task? If not, what is the way to access the file system on the phone? How to get to the phone data using Windows system API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADB stands for Android Debug Bridge; it is the official command line tool and provides shell terminal access to Android phones that has allowed developer debug access.

There seems to be 3rd-party python API for this.
https://github.com/google/python-adb